# destroy method of a resource controller can respond to GET request method While should not be able to

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a global resource controller and make a route from that like this:

```
Route::resource('cat', 'CategoryController');
```

In the `CategoryController` class is `destroy` method like this :

```
public function destroy (\App\Category $cat)
{
    $cat->delete();
    return ['success' => true, 'msg' => 'Category removed'];
}
```

Now According to [Docs about RESTful Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) `destroy` should can respond to requests that sent via **DELETE** method. but in this case it can respond to requests that sent via **GET** method too And that makes me wonder.

What happens to it?

I'm using laravel  5.3.4.

**Update :**
This is my Full `CategoryController` :

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
    {

        public function index ()
        {
            return view('admin/pages/post/category_manage');
        }

        public function create ()
        {

        }

        public function store (Request $request)
        {

            $result = ['success' => true, 'msg' => 'عملیات با موفقیت انجام شد'];

            $allData = $request->only('text', 'parent');

            $rules = array (
                'text'   => 'required|min:2',
                'parent' => 'required'
            );

            $validator = \Validator::make($allData, $rules);
            if ($validator->fails()) {

                $result = ['success' => false, 'msg' => $validator->errors()->first()];

            } else {

                if ($allData['parent'] == '#') {
                    $root = NULL;
                } else {
                    $root = Category::find($allData['parent']);
                }

                $newCategory = Category::create(['name' => $allData['text']]);
                if (is_null($root)) {
                    $newCategory->makeRoot();
                } else {
                    $newCategory->makeChildOf($root);
                }

                $result['generated_id'] = $newCategory->cat_id;

            }

            return $result;

        }

        public function show ($cat_alias)
        {

            return $cat_alias;
            $category = Category::whereCatAlias($cat_alias)->firstOrFail();

            $postCategory = Post::active()->scheduled()->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($cat_alias) {
                $query->whereCatAlias($cat_alias);
            })
                ->select(['post_title', 'post_sub_title', 'post_alias', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'created_at', 'hits', 'picture'])
                ->paginate(15);


//          return $postCategory;

            return view('main.pages.category', ['postsCategories' => $postCategory, 'category' => $category]);
        }

        public function edit ($id)
        {
            //
        }

        public function update ($id, Request $request)
        {
            $result = ['success' => true, 'msg' => 'عملیات با موفقیت انجام شد'];

            $allData = $request->only('text', 'old');
            $rules   = array (
                'text' => 'required|min:2',
                'old'  => 'required'
            );

            $validator = \Validator::make($allData, $rules);
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                $result = ['success' => false, 'msg' => $validator->errors()->first()];
            } else {
                $node        = Category::find($id);
                $newCategory = $node->update(['name' => $allData['text']]);
            }

            return $result;

        }

        public function destroy (\App\Category $cat)
        {
            $cat->delete();
            return ['success' => true, 'msg' => 'Category removed'];
        }
    }
```

And full Routes:

```
Route::resource('cat', 'CategoryController');
Route::group(
            array (
                'prefix' => 'admin',
                'as'     => 'admin.',
                'middleware' => 'auth'
            ),
            function () {
                   Route::group(['prefix' => 'post'], function () {         
                       Route::resource('category', 'CategoryController');
                    });
             });
});
```

As yu can see there is another resource controller refers to `CategoryController` named `category` in a protected route group.

Comment: when you go to api/cat/1 with GET request you get "Category removed" ?

Comment: @Bara'ayyash, Yes exactly. Of course I do not work on an api, there is a website and I call for example: `http://example.com/cat/1`.

Comment: There must be some mistake. I have used resource many times. destroy() must be accessed through DELETE request only. Can you show more route  and controller code? And how you are making that request? Using form submission or postman?

Comment: i think there is something wrong with the headers.. try to use POSTMAN to make a GET request and see what will happen

Comment: @Bara'ayyash, I tried both web browser and Postman and both have same result : removing category.

Comment: can you please post the full code of the controller ?

Comment: @Bara'ayyash,@ParthVora , I added new information.

Comment: i think the problem comes from `Route::group`, try to comment that route and see what will happen

Comment: can you run `php artisan route:list` to check what method on destroy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the 2 resource routes on `CategoryController` are conflicting.

Can you try to implement them this way?

```
Route::resource('cat', 'CategoryController', ['except' => 'destroy']);
Route::delete('cat', ['as' => 'cat.destroy', 'uses' => 'CategoryController@destroy']);
```

Also, it's pretty messy to implement routes the way you did, try to write them as explicit as possible to prevent weird bugs like the one you're experiencing.

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030097/how-to-add-some-textfield-in-form-register-laravel-generator-infyom